# does addition from Game engines require needs during development?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

Once I have created a new engine which has things like better dialog and better A.I, if I select that during the development of the game does that mean that I could lower the correlating field during the Dev so that I could concentrate on other sections or does it mean that I should look more into that specific area of the game?

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a feature requires a certain amount of time spent on its area during development, if you don't give that area enough dev time, a percentage will appear next to its name on the right, showing you how much of the required time you have alloted. While the precise effect is not known, I assume adding loads of half-baked features will do your game no favors. If you're optimizing sliders for the genre, I would suggest adding as many sensible features as possible without the percentage appearing.